# How to handle CSRF token with Firebase, Angular, and Express?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, firebase-authentication, csrf

I want to use a CSRF token, and I understand that for each form submission, I need to send my CSRF token. The token is generated once when a user signs in (it's a random UID). Here's what happens during sign-in: In Angular, I sign in the user, which gives me an ID token. Then, I generate a UID for my CSRF token. I send this to my backend, which creates two HTTP-only cookies: one with the session cookie obtained by exchanging the ID token, and the other with the CSRF token, which is simply the random UID.

The idea is that for each subsequent request, I compare the UID from the form to the one stored in the cookie. If they match, it's okay. However, the problem arises because the session cookie is valid for two weeks. When the user closes their browser, they remain logged in, but the random UID is lost. However, the CSRF cookie remains. So, for each request the user makes thereafter, there won't be the same CSRF token, and the request won't be authorized.

I think I'm missing something, and I don't think I'm approaching this the right way. Can anyone help me?

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { getAuth } from "firebase-admin/auth";
const sessionRouter = Router();

sessionRouter.post("/", (req, res) => {
  // Get the ID token passed and the CSRF token.
  const idToken = req.body.idToken.toString();
  const csrfToken = req.body.csrfToken.toString();
  // Guard against CSRF attacks.
  if (!csrfToken) {
    res.status(401).send("UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST!");
    return;
  }
  // Set session expiration to 14 days.
  const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 14 * 1000;
  // Create the session cookie. This will also verify the ID token in the process.
  // The session cookie will have the same claims as the ID token.
  // To only allow session cookie setting on recent sign-in, auth_time in ID token
  // can be checked to ensure user was recently signed in before creating a session cookie.
  getAuth()
    .createSessionCookie(idToken, { expiresIn })
    .then(
      (sessionCookie) => {
        // Set cookie policy for session cookie.
        const options = {
          maxAge: expiresIn,
          httpOnly: true,
          secure: false,
          samesite: "None",
        };
        res.cookie("session", sessionCookie, options);
        res.cookie("csrfToken", csrfToken, options);
        res.end(JSON.stringify({ status: "success" }));
      },
      (error) => {
        res.status(401).send("UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST!");
      }
    );
});

export default sessionRouter;
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment.development';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import {
  getAuth,
  setPersistence,
  inMemoryPersistence,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  UserCredential,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import { UuidService } from './uuid.service';
import { RequestService } from './request.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FirebaseAuthService {
  app = initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig);
  auth = getAuth(this.app);

  constructor(
    private uuidService: UuidService,
    private router: Router,
    private requestService: RequestService
  ) {
    setPersistence(this.auth, inMemoryPersistence);
  }

  async signIn(email: string, password: string) {
    try {
      const userCredential: UserCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        this.auth,
        email,
        password
      );
      const csrfToken = this.uuidService.uuidValue;
      const idToken = await userCredential.user.getIdToken();
      this.requestService.postIdTokenToSessionLogin(idToken, csrfToken);
    } catch (error) {}
  }
}

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment.development';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class RequestService {
  URL = environment.url;
  HEADERS = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };
  constructor() {}

  async postIdTokenToSessionLogin(idToken: string, csrfToken: string) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${this.URL}/sessionLogin`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: this.HEADERS,
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify({ idToken, csrfToken }),
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log('Réponse du serveur :', data);
    } catch (error) {}
  }
}


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UuidService {
  uuid = '';

  constructor() {
    this.uuid = uuidv4();
  }

  get uuidValue() {
    return this.uuid;
  }
}
```

Comment: ideally you want the anti-csrf token to be unique per request... that'll help prevent CRIME/BREACH attacks.  It's something that would be set per GET, then sent along with the POSTed form data (or in custom header) and compared with another cookie that is also tied to the session.  (sometimes a private key is used to encode/decode these and check that they match).  At minimum, you should generate a new anti-csrf value each time the user is checked/authenticated via session cookie.  You need to store that value so that it can be included with response to GETs that have form data to be posted.

Comment: The short-road is to just require each state-changing request to have a custom header.  This can be any value... the backend just needs to require it.  This would prevent any simple request from going through, so the browser's CORS requirements would prevent a CSRF attack.  (Unless the server has loosened CORS restrictions by responding with CORS headers that allow cross-domain requests)

Comment: setting your session cookie to same-site: strict; will also help here (it would prevent csrf but also automatic login when clicking a link from say Google listing)

Comment: Thanks you i think i understood, but when the user sign in there is no csrf token right ?

Comment: Usually there is no session begun before login so no need for anti-csrf.  (there's no session to hijack)   There are exceptions to that, but if there is a session before it's important to begin another after logging in or you're open to session fixation attack.  (If login is handled  automatically via cert or negotiate etc... then you might have a session before login)

Comment: If I understand correctly, when the user signs in, the server generates a CSRF token simultaneously with the sessionCookie. The server then sends the sessionCookie along with a csrfCookie containing the CSRF token back to the client. For each form, the server generates a CSRF token upon loading and sends it back to the client. This is typically done through a method that involves a GET request, and the token is placed in a cookie called csrfCookie, correct?

Comment: the important part is to tie the form to the session.  The anti-csrf value will be in the form itself in a hidden field.  This is then checked against the anti-csrf cookie.  (I think they call this method the double-submit cookie).  See here: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#signed-double-submit-cookie-recommended  If you don't use a hidden field, you can use a custom header... you'd read that value from the front-end by having the server send a non-http-only cookie.  Angular has HttpClientXsrfModule for this.

Comment: Read here for double-submit cookie pattern: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#signed-double-submit-cookie-recommended  (Usually this stuff is just built-in to the server-side framework, but it seems like you're having to do a lot of the work here...)

Comment: And synchronizer-pattern: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#synchronizer-token-pattern

Comment: also remember that CSRF attacks should only be possible if that request can be sent as a simple request.  In Angular's context this is usually only true if you ever send a FormData() object.  (FormData() is often used when uploading files...)  All Fetch requests are non-simple...(so CORS pre-flight check happens) but backends that accept FormData can usually be reached via a simple POST as well.

Comment: I read about the synchronizer pattern, and if I want to generate a token for each request, how can I store the valid token (I'm using Firebase)? Maybe when a user has a form, we can make a GET request to obtain the token in the response and then set a HTTP-only cookie with the same token? So afterward, I can check if the token in the form matches the one in the HTTP-only cookie?

Comment: And I have a question: I generate the token on the server-side and I put the token in a simple cookie. I use HttpInterceptor because it will put the token from this simple cookie in the header for all requests. But is putting the token in a simple cookie really secure? Like, can the token be stolen by JavaScript, right?

Comment: it's common to send a non-http-only cookie for each request (if this is unique for each request, this will prevent CRIME/BREACH attacks, too).  Then the front-end will read that cookie and send it as a custom header for each state-changing request.  It's OK for this to be stolen.  I believe this will be encrypted and then decrypted server-side with private key to see if it matches the http-only cookie... (which is tied to the session in some way...) The CSRF attacker never has the session so they can't generate that non-http-only cookie... it was sent on the last request.

Comment: If the attacker can run their own javascript (XSS attack) then they can force the user to make any request... no need to read the cookie or hidden field.  You'll always want to protect against XSS... they could also prompt the user for username/password and send it to the attacker...  while using an http-only cookie for session tokens will protect against XSS stealing them, it won't protect against all forms of XSS attacks...

Comment: when I said encrypt/decrypt with private key that might be misleading.  I just mean only the server has that key.  I believe this key rotates.  It's used to encrypt/decrypt the anti-csrf token.  The unencrypted value must match the http-only cookie.   The http-only cookie is set per session.  The anti-csrf token changes per request.

Comment: modern browser will use CORS rules so be sure you don't loosen those by sending CORS headers.  Same-site cookies will also help, and X-Frame-Options: DENY and/or CSP headers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options